# Magento failing to add every other product to the cart

Tags: php, magento, cart

As above, I've got a strange issue where every other product I add isn't added to the cart or quote in Magento.

It's repeatable, in that I can add one product, then the next one doesn't add (but I do get a status messaging saying it was added), and then the next done after that adds as it should do.

It's not specific to a product, as if I add the same product a second time it will add as expected.

The only thing we have that's a little different is an observer called on the sales_quote_add_item event, but that's just changing the pricing:

```
public function update_book_price(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {


//get the admin session
Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name'=>'adminhtml'));


if (!$quoteitem = $observer->getQuoteItem()){
    $quoteitem = $observer->getItem();
}
if (!$item = $observer->getEvent()->getQuoteItem()){
    $item = $quoteitem;
}
$quote = $item->getQuote();

$product = $item->getProduct();


        $price = Mage::helper('users')->getCustomerProductPrice(false,Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product['product_id']),false,true,$_POST['qtys'][$product['product_id']]);

                    echo "Price : $price \n";
    //print_r($price);
    $price = $price;


        if(!$quoteitem->setOriginalCustomPrice($price)) {

            echo "Couldn't set price";


        }
        else {
                            echo "price updated, save";
                            try { 
                $quoteitem->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
                    var_dump($quoteitem->save());
                            }catch(Exception $e){
                                echo $e->getMessage() . "\n";
                            }

        }


    return $this;
}
```

I've checked at a DB level, and the missing items are not even in the DB - sales_flat_quote_item has no record of them, but the 'working' items are in as normal.

Has anyone experienced anything like this before, or can anyone suggest where I might start investigating? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to save quote item after changing price.

Delete `var_dump($quoteitem->save());` and try again.